# creating a method to return the average of values of an array

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a static method within a class that is passed an array of array objects and returns the average value of the objects in the array.

```
public static double calcAverage() {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < people.length; i++)
            sum = sum + people[i];
  double calcAverage() = sum / people.length
     System.out.println(people.calcAverage());
}
```

The code is getting compilation errors but am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like it's going to have some infinite recursion once you get it compiling. Move the `println` somewhere else. In `main` perhaps.

Comment: double calcAverage() is wrong, declare a variable  double avgVal = sum / people.length; and print avgVal

Comment: How/where is people declared?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double calcAverage() {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < people.length; i++)
            sum = sum + people[i];
  double calcAverage() = sum / people.length
     System.out.println(people.calcAverage());
}
```

Change

```
  double calcAverage() = sum / people.length
```

to

```
  double average = sum / (double)people.length;
```

(The correct way to declare a new variable)

Change

```
     System.out.println(people.calcAverage());
```

to

```
  return average;
```

(If you want to print the result of calling the function, you should always do it outside of the function, e.g. do it in `main` after calling the function and storing the returned result)

so we have:

```
public static double calcAverage() {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < people.length; i++)
  {
       sum = sum + people[i];
  }
  double average = sum / (double)people.length;
  return average;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason it is still not accepting it.. trying to figure out why

Comment: @aiuna What is the exact error message and line number you are getting?

Comment: figured it out, thanks alot!

Comment: @aiuna Cool, don't forget the `(double)` cast I added in, if you don't do it it'll compute it as integer division which rounds decimal points out of existence

Answer (score 1):

your close. I see a few mistakes though.

First your sum = sum + people[i];

people[i] returns is object not a integer so adding a object to a integer wont work.

second, you are calling your calcAverage() inside the calcAverage method which is probably NOT what you want to do. Doing this is called recursion but i think you should be calling method outside of calcAverage().

Answer (score 1):

```
// pass people as a parameter
public static double calcAverage(int[] people) {
   // IMPORTANT: this must be a double, otherwise you're dividing an integer by an integer and you will get the wrong answer
   double sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i < people.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + people[i];
   }
   // remove the ()
   double result = sum / people.length;
   System.out.println(result);

   // return something
   return result;
}


// example
int[] myPeople = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
double myPeopleAverage = calcAverage(myPeople);
```

Comment: had to fix some stuff on my part, thanks alot